# NVIC memory map ARM cortex M3 STM32f103

Tags: arm, interrupts, register

I do not understand the following memory map regarding the NVIC registers in Programming Manual for [STM32f103](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/5b/ca/8d/83/56/7f/40/08/CD00228163.pdf/files/CD00228163.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00228163.pdf) page 129. It says that the offset address for NVIC_IPR0 is 0x300 and that of NVIC_IPR20 is 0x320. I do not understand how is this possible?! I think that the offset for NVIC_IPR20 should be 0x350. Indeed, assuming the registers follow one after another one obtains something like this:

NVIC_IPR0 -> 0x300

NVIC_IPR1 -> 0x304

NVIC_IPR2 -> 0x308

etc.

NVIC_IPR20 -> 0x350

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct -- that looks like a typo. The offset for that register should be `0x350`.

The CMSIS header file (`core_cm3.h`) avoids the issue entirely by defining `NVIC->IP` as an array of bytes, not of 32-bit words:

```
__IO uint8_t  IP[240];                      /*!< Offset: 0x300  Interrupt Priority Register (8Bit wide) */
```

This documentation error was probably the result of confusion between the byte-wise structure used by ARM and the 32-bit structure used by ST.

Comment: Sir, by the way, why the IP has 240 values? There, in the programming manual I see that there are just 21 registers each having 4 bytes, therefore it seems that IP[84] should have been enough ... right?

Comment: For the STM32F103, yes, that'd be sufficient. But the CMSIS header was written by ARM to support _any_ Cortex-M3 microcontroller, not just this one; as such, it's been put together to support up to 240 interrupts (which I believe is the most the architecture could possibly support).

Comment: ok, thank you very much!